# IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

beginner in python, please take a look at the below code:

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':

     n = int(sys.argv[1]) 
     i=1
     s=0
     while i<n:
            if (i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0): 
                pass
            elif (i % 3 == 0): 
                s = s+i
            elif (i % 5 == 0):
                s = s+i 
            i=i+1
     print 'The sum is of all 3s and 5s till {}: {}'.format(n,s)
```

The error keeps coming out, I don't know how to solve it:

```
      2 import sys
      3 if __name__ == '__main__':
----> 4     n = int(sys.argv[1])
      5     i=1
      6     s=0

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank you!

Comment: How are you calling/running your python script?

Comment: I just use the command line in Canopy

Comment: You should be calling it like `python script.py argument`.

Comment: i can do that in terminal, but can i also do that in canopy?

Comment: @AlbertYu try this script `import sys
if __name__ == '__main__': print sys.argv` and run `python script.py 1`. after this run `python script.py 1 2 3` and you will understand how it works

Answer (score 1):

You need to send at least one argument when calling the program (call it like `> euler_1.py 1000`), since the arguments are stored in `sys.argv[1:]`.

You can avoid this need by setting a default when no argument is supplied:

```
n = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 1000
```

Comment: but i only have one input argument here

Comment: `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the program, arguments start from index `1`